# Possible bug with `FindSequenceFunction`$.$

Tags: sequence

Consider the following code:

```
g = Table[Sign[StieltjesGamma[n]], {n, 0, 30}];
s = FindSequenceFunction[g];
```

The result is a certain `DifferenceRoot` object (too long to include here), which essentially solves the recurrence relation
$$
a_{n+1}=a_n
$$
with "initial conditions" $a_i=g_i$. In other words, the `DifferenceRoot` is actually storing the first 30 elements of `g` as initial conditions, and predicting the rest to be a constant sequence:
$$
s_i=\begin{cases}g_i & i\in[1,30]\\ 1 & i>30\end{cases}
$$

This is obviously cheating: you could do the same thing to *any* sequence, that is, store all the known elements as initial conditions to an arbitrary recurrence relation, and predict the rest using that recurrence relation. Such a prediction would be meaningless. Is this behaviour of `FindSequenceFunction` a bug?

Note that in this case there is no known closed-form expression for `g`, so `s` should be returned unevaluated. In fact, that's what I expected to get; the `DifferenceRoot` object was certainly a surprise. In any case, there is nothing special about the Stieltjes constants: the sequence `g` can be replaced with any random sequence of integers, such as

```
SeedRandom[1]
g = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, 30];
```

which has the same behaviour: `FindSequenceFunction` returns a `DifferenceRoot` object that stores the elements of `g` as initial conditions to an (arbitrarily chosen?) recurrence relation.

Comment: I'm not sure what tags to use here. Please feel free to edit them. I do know I'm not supposed to add the `bug` one though...

Comment: why this should be a bug? In this way, and as you note, `FindSequenceFunction` can predict any element of the sequence, can't it? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas It doesn't "predict" anything. It just stores what you already know, and fails to predict the rest of the sequence. Note that the Stieltjes constants are **not** all positive for $i>30$, unlike what `s` suggests.

Comment: note you do not get such result for every random sequence.

Comment: `FindSequenceFunction` makes no claim at being predictive.  You may be  right it is a useless result, but not a bug.

Comment: @george2079 I was under the impression that ìf `FindSequenceFunction` wasn't sure about the predictor, it would return unevaluated. You get an actual output only when the function has reasons to believe the predictor is meaningful (according to some criterion, say, number of fitting parameters over the input elements). Am I wrong?

Comment: From documentation:"FindSequenceFunction[{Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 2], Subscript[a, 3], ...}] 
attempts to find a simple function that yields the sequence Subscript[a, n] when given successive integer arguments." and  "FindSequenceFunction[list] only returns functions that correctly reproduce all elements of list." That is, it only tries to reproduce `list` with a `simple function`. If the `list` originates from a `simple function` then it may find that function; however, if underlying function is not sufficiently `simple` then you can only expect to be able to reproduce the input list.

Comment: In other words: not a bug per se, but a highly misleading (and IMHO inconsistent) behaviour. Thank you peeps!